# Abstracting UDP and TCP send/receive procedures

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

Good day.

**Intro.**

Recently I've started to study some 'low-level' network programming as well as networking protocols in Linux. For this purpose I decided to create a small library for networking.

And now I wonder on some questions. I will ask one of them now.

As you know there are at least two protocols built on top of IP. I talk about TCP and UDP. Their implementation may differ in OS due to connection-orientation property of those.

According to `man 7 udp` all receive operations on UDP socket return only one packet. It is rational as different datagrams may come from different sources.

On the other hand TCP connection packets sequence may be considered as continuous byte flow.

**Now, about the problem itself.**

Say, I have an API for TCP connection socket and for UDP socket like:

```
void tcp_connection_recv(endpoint_t *ep, buffer_t *b);
void udp_recv(endpoint_t *ep, buffer_t *b);
```

`endpoint_t` type will describe the endpoint (remote for TCP connection and local for UDP). `buffer_t` type will describe some kind of vector-based or array-based buffer.

It is quite possible that buffer is already allocated by user and I'm not sure that this will be right for UDP to not change size of the buffer. And thus, to abstract code for TCP and UDP operations I think it will need to allocate as much buffer as needed to contain whole received data.
Also, to prevent from resizeing user buffer each socket may be maped to its own buffer (although it will be userspace buffer, but it will be hidden from user). And then on user's request data will be copied from that 'inner' buffer to user's one or read from socket if there is not enough amount.

Any suggestions or opinions?

Comment: Why don't you follow some of already existing implementations? Much though was put into their API, so you can learn from them.

Comment: @SergeyA I did use Boost implementation but was quite curious about my own implementation as it will be very useful for me to know smth about protols below application level in OSI model.

Comment: That's cool. But you should still look into APIs. In particular, you will learn what to do with the buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create such API, it will depend on the service you want to provide. In TCP it will be different than UDP as TCP is stream oriented.

For TCP, tcp_connection_recv instead of reallocating a buffer, if the buffer passed by the user is not big enough, you can fill the whole buffer and then return, maybe with an output parameter, and indication that there is more data waiting to be read. Basically you can use the receive buffer that TCP connection already provides in the kernel, no need to create other buffer.

For, udp, you can request the user a number indicating the maximum datagram size it is waiting for. When you read from a UDP socket with recvfrom, if you read less data than what came in the arrived datagram, the rest of the datagram data is lost. You can read first with MSG_PEEK flag in order to find out how much data is available.

In general I wouldn't handle the buffer for the application as the application, actually the application layer protocol, is the one that knows how it expects to receive the data.

Comment: How about using `SIOCINQ` ioctl to find out first datagram length?

Comment: @SergeyKanaev, you are right, just consider the corresponding comment in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html

Comment: Maybe you have any suggestions on `send` API either?

Comment: @SergeyKanaev, send should be easier because the developer knows what they want to send. So endpoint and buffer, including buffer length, should be OK.